# How do you get an HTML element ID to autocomplete in VSCode JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

[image: VSCode on top, Visual Studio Community on bottom]

I'm trying to get intellisense to work with JavaScript in VSCode, but when I try to reference an HTML file in the project it doesn't recognize IDs.

In the picture you can see the same project works fine in Visual Studio.

Is there a way to get this functionality in VSCode?

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't just list a bunch of tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, Visual Studio and VS Code are two completely different software's. Visual Studio is an IDE (Integrated Development Environment), this means it has more features than a normal text editor (for example VS Code or Atom). VS Code is a text editor, however you can install extensions to make it more into an IDE.

The best solution is to look at VS Codes market place and try and find an extension that will auto complete the HTML tags. I personally haven't found any extension for it.

Hope this helps, if you need any more advice or help DM me on discord CallumS005#9458 and I'll be happy to try and help.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Glad I wasn't missing something obvious.

Comment: @RyanDaniels you can never be too sure if you are missing something obvious with VS Code, so simple but yet so complex at the same time